# Update view from controller (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a situation like this:

[image: Two View Controller and One View]

If I click on left foot button I want that my view in the second controller show a left foot image, and if I click on right button the view should show right foot image.

In the first controller I wrote this to select right or left:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    RSViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Left-Foot"])
        [vc setLeft:YES];
    else
        [vc setLeft:NO];
}
```

In the second controller I have a method which set a boolean value

```
- (void)setLeft:(BOOL)left
{
    if (left) {
        _left = left;
        NSLog(@"LEFT UPDATED IN RSVIEWCONTROLLER");
    }else {
        _left = left;
        NSLog(@"RIGHT UPDATED IN RSVIEWCONTROLLER");
    }
}
```

and in the same controller I create my view in viewdidload with my one init:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"meeeea");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    self.animatedCircleView = [[RSAnimatedCircleView alloc] initWithFrameFoot:rect foot:YES];
    NSLog(@"Viewdidnoload");
}
```

and in my view (small blue rectangle in the picture):

```
- (void)setup:(BOOL)left
{
 self.leftFoot = left;
}

- (void)setLeftFoot:(BOOL)leftFoot
{
    _leftFoot = leftFoot;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setup:_leftFoot];
}

- (id)initWithFrameFoot:(CGRect)frame foot:(BOOL)left
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup:left];
    self.leftFoot = left;

    if (self.leftFoot)
        NSLog(@"Left == TRUE");

    return self;

}

- (RSFootView *)footView
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    if (self.leftFoot) {
        NSLog(@"Now left is yes");

    }else {
        NSLog(@"left is no");
    }

    _footView = [[RSFootView alloc] initWithFrame:rect withLeftFoot:self.leftFoot];
    [_footView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    return _footView;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.leftFoot)
        NSLog(@"left ada");
    else
        NSLog(@"right masd");

    CGFloat x = self.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat y = self.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat radius = x/2 - 15;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(x/2, y/2);
    CGFloat startAngle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(START_ANGLE);
    CGFloat endAngle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(END_ANGLE);

    // Drawing the sector
    UIBezierPath *sector = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                          radius:radius
                                                      startAngle:startAngle
                                                        endAngle:endAngle
                                                       clockwise:YES];

    sector.lineWidth = 4;

    [[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];
    [sector stroke];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [sector addClip];

    [self addSubview:self.footView];

}
```

in the method "drawRect" the leftfoot value is always false. I do not know why is like this... can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your view to "left" each time in the following line.

```
   self.animatedCircleView = [[RSAnimatedCircleView alloc] 
          initWithFrameFoot:rect foot:YES];
```

This is a typical error that becomes very probable when not giving your variables and methods understandable and intuitive names. Expect this type of error to occur frequently if you do not mend your ways.

I would give your view an enum property that states explicitly what foot it is:

```
typedef enum {LeftFoot, RightFoot} FootType; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) FootType footType;
```

Also, you should revise your method names. I would completely do away with the `initWithFrameFoot` method and just set a default foot in your override for `initWithFrame`. (Leaving it at 0 amounts to `LeftFoot`.)  With `@synthesize` you also do not need a setter or getter. Delete them.

If you want a dedicated initializer, make sure the variable passed are actually preceded by the proper words.

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect andFootType:(FootType)footType {
    self = [super initWithFrame:rect]; 
    if (self) {
         _footType = footType;  
    }
    return self;
}
```

After using `@synthesize` you can set the correct foot in `prepareForSegue:`

```
footViewController.footType = rightFoot;
```